# a consistent model of $\mathbb{N}$ that isn't?

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

(*This question arose from a homework question which asked me to prove that (1st order) induction is independent from the other (1st order) Peano axioms*)

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language of Peano arithmetic, i.e. with $0$ the only constant symbol, $+$, $\cdot$, and $S$ (the successor function) the only function symbols, and $=$ the only predicate symbol. Let $A$ be the theory in $\mathcal{L}$ whose axioms are the Peano axioms. Denote by $\overline{n}$ the term $S(S(\cdots S(0)\cdots))$, where $S$ is applied to $n$ times to $0$.

Next, extend $\mathcal{L}$ to a language $\mathcal{L}'$ with a single new constant symbol $\omega$. Let $A_1$ be $A$ extended to $\mathcal{L}'$, and set
$$ A'=A_1\cup\{\overline{0}<\omega,\,\overline{1}<\omega,\,\overline{2}<\omega,\,\ldots\}.$$

#### $A'$ is consistent:

Let $T=A_1\cup\{\overline{i_1}<\omega,\,\overline{i_1}<\omega,\,\ldots,\overline{i_n}<\omega\}$, where $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ are natural numbers (if $n=0$, set $T=A_1$). Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the standard model of $A$. Then $\mathbb{N}$ may be interpreted as a model of $T$ by interpreting $\omega$ to be $\max\{i_0,\ldots,i_n\}+1$. Hence, $T$ is consistent. Thus, by the compactness theorem, $A'$ is consistent.

#### Question:

Let $M$ be a normal model of $A'$. Then $M$ is also an interpretation of $\mathcal{L}$, and all the axioms of $A$ are true in $M$ since they're also axioms of $A'$. So, $M$ is a model of $A$.

On the other hand, $\vdash_A x\neq0\Rightarrow (\exists y)(x=S(y))$. So, since $M$ is a model of $A$, it follows that $\models_M x\neq0\Rightarrow (\exists y)(x=S(y))$. So, 
$\omega\in M$ is the successor of some object in $M$. Repeating this, we get a sequence
$$\omega>\omega-1>\omega-2>\cdots$$
in $M$ with no minimal element. But this contradicts the well ordering theorem, which is a theorem of $A$!

Where did I mess up?

Comment: You may want to be more precise: First order induction is part of the first order Peano axioms, so I doubt that you were asked to show independence (as it is false). Perhaps you mean that first order induction is independent from *the other* axioms? Even this is confusing, as first-order induction is an infinite list of statements.

Comment: Perhaps more relevant to the present question: What do you mean by a "normal" model?

Comment: Also, your title has issues: $\mathbb N$ is a structure, not a theory. How can you have models of a structure? What does it mean for a model to be inconsistent? For that matter, what does it mean for a model to be consistent? Consistency, after all, is a property of *theories*, not of structures.

Comment: The induction axiom scheme ensures that any non-empty definable subset of a model has a smallest element. A non-standard model is never well-ordered.

Comment: The compactness argument you've given isn't quite right as it stands. You need to show that given any finite set of axioms $T \subseteq A'$, $\mathbb{N} \models T$. This is done pretty much in the way you suggest: clearly any $\varphi \in T \cap A_1$ is satisfied, so then let $\omega$ be the least natural number greater than those picked out by numerals in sentences of $T$. But you can't just pick some particular $T$ as it seems like you're doing currently: it must be an arbitrary finite subset of $A'$.

Comment: The language of your theory $A$ is too weak to express the existence or non-existence of infinite descending sequences. You need to rethink your claim that the "well-ordering theorem" (or whatever you meant by that) is a theorem of $A$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: A "normal" model is one whose interpretation of the "$=$" predicate is the identity relation on its universe. (This is a useful concept if your formal system considers $=$ to be just some binary predicate rather than a logical primitive, and it is up to the the theory to supply explicit axioms for the behavior of it).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be a formula of our language, possibly extended to contain constant symbols for the elements of $M$. It is true in $M$ that if there is an $x$ such that $\varphi(x,m_1,m_2,\dots, m_k)$, then there is a smallest such $x$. However, the set that you described informally cannot be captured by any such $\varphi$: your argument is a proof of that.